# Reminders inside a task manager

Tags: python, reminders

This is my program. My problem is I would like my reminders to go off on their respective times without having to go through the program first. But they aren't going off until after the program questions have been answered.

```
import pip 
import time
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    Start = input('Is the schedule finished? ')
    if Start == ('yes'):
        print('Start sending emails')
        for i in range(1):
            time.sleep(10)
        question = input('Have you finished day one emails? ')
        if question == ('no'):
         print('Finish emails by 0830.')
        time.sleep(10)
        question = input('Have you finished day one emails? ')
        if question == ('no'):
                print('Finish emails by 0830.')
                time.sleep(10)
                question = input('Have you finished day one emails? ')
                if question == ('no'):
                    print("You're going to fall behind.")
                elif question == ('yes'):
                    print('Start day two.')
        elif question == ('yes'):
            print('Start day two.')
    elif Start == ('no'):
        print('Finish schedule')

    reminders = [
    # Put all of your reminders here
    # Drink water notification would be set multiple times
    ('2022-02-19 22:12:00', 'Eat Lunch'),
    ('2022-02-19 22:13:00', 'Drink water')
    ]


    reminders2 = {datetime.fromisoformat(reminder[0]).timestamp(): reminder[1] for reminder in reminders}

    while True:
        now = time.time()
        for timestamp, reminder_msg in reminders2.items():
            if timestamp < now:
                print(reminder_msg)
                del reminders2[timestamp]
                break
        time.sleep(1)
    
main()
```

Comment: put first part in separated function and use `if/else` with `input()` to decide if run this function. OR use `sys.args` to get parameter from command line and use `if/else` to check it and run or skip this function.

Comment: in `if/elif/else` you don't have to put text in `( )` - simply do `if Start == 'yes':`

Comment: Will that allow the reminder function statement to pop up while the other one is running?

Comment: I don't understand waht is the problem. Maybe first try, next ask questions.

Comment: When I run/debug the program, the reminders don't process until after all the questions are answered. I would like the reminders to happen while the first function is running. So if I answer "no" to "Have you finished sending day one emails?". Is it possible for the reminders to to pop up first (depending on the time they're set for) before it asks "Have you finished sending day one emails?" again? I tried putting them before and inside the main function, but the reminders always prevent the main function from running. That is why I put them after main.

Comment: Sorry if I am not explaining this well, I am fairly new to programming.